# how to get SensorEvent's value when "onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)" not called?

Tags: android, android-sensors

If I register a listener after the sensor has changed something, I cannot get the changed value and have to wait for the next time when `onSensorChanged` get called. Is there any way to get current sensor's value in such situation?

Comment: what sensor do you use?

Comment: Not a standard sensor, a sensor checks if a device is on body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sensor information is only available as SensorEvent in the method onSensorChanged. So without onSensorChanged it will not be possible to get the sensor Events

Answer (score 0):

That seems impossible,once register the sensor,when the data is changing,the function onSensorChanged  will callback